# Display image in Background Url from MongoDB using NodeJS and Angular6

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have created an image uploader on my site and store the URL in my MongoDB. I used this guide to create my image uploader: https://appdividend.com/2018/05/25/angular-6-file-upload-tutorial/
However, when the file is stored in my MongoDB table it is a C:\\fakepath\\ url. When I try to display the url in a background-image url field via ngStyle I get the response:

```
Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
```

Here is my code for the .html page:

```
<div class="jumbotron" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + post.image + ')'}"></div>
```

The rest of the code follows suit to the guide for storing the image.

If there is a way to either modify the url before it is in the MongoDB or to eliminate the C:\\fakepath\\ and just append the end to the ./upload/ folder where the image is stored should work as well. I have tried also just using the {{post.image}} syntax and recieve the same result.

Comment: When you are thinking of your database, backend app, and frontend app in this kind of situation, your design probably needs rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check the network call if you're really receiving the data
>   (post and url) from backend.

If you are then check the logic where you assign the backend response to variable post.

> From the error, it seems that post has no value. Or you accessing it
>   the wrong way. Check if post is `yourCtrl.post` or something.

Comment: For everything else I pull such as the body from the collection called post, it is {{post.body}} and that will import perfectly. It's just the images, this works if I use nGModel as well for pulling the body text.

Comment: Are you able to pull body in the same html? because from the error it looks like post doesn't have any value. Can you please share more code where you are assigning/fetching values to/from post?

Comment: I think I found the issue now that I was comparing stored images compared to url in the database. First here is how the stored html goes for post.image: `<input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" class="uploads" [(ngModel)]="post.image"/>` Next, since it runs through a path and file uploader from the guide above. It changes the name after it runs and is stored in database under different name. In upload folder: `photo-1538621204997..png` In database: `C:\\fakepath\\Screen Shot 2017-05-14 at 10.57.28 AM.png` Know of a way to change this?

Comment: Great! I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you can add your logic before saving to the database. Usually people create a pattern name for each file and then save.

Comment: How can I do that, if the change event is on the button but the field value itself is on the input control? Here is code for both, input: `<input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" class="uploads" [(ngModel)]="post.image"/>` button: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s uploadBtn" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
                            Upload an Image
                        </button>` Also thanks for the help, I'm new to these ways of development.

Comment: The uploader.uploadAll() must be fireing some api/ajax req which in results saves the url to database. So you have to find handler/controller for this api in backed and there you can modify the file name just before saving to database and send that name in response from backend.

Comment: I have more good news, I found where the file naming convention was held and I changed it to be the original file name when saving to the server. Now the only thing left, would be if I could get the path ./upload/filename.png instead of C:\\fakepath\\.filename.png from the database, it should display when I will just use the {{post.image}} pulling from the database. Is there a way to take that path off of this either before right to database or when pulling from?